# Pomegranate HMM labels: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Tags: python, arrays, boolean, hidden-markov-models, valueerror

I'm using the [Pomegranate library](http://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HiddenMarkovModel.html)  for an HMM implementation. I'm following what the docs say for using the `from_samples` function which says that one of the parameters `labels` should be:

`An array of state labels for each sequence. This is only used in ‘labeled’ training. If used this must be comprised of n lists where n is the number of sequences to train on, and each of those lists must have one label per observation. Default is None.`

My code is:

```
model = HiddenMarkovModel('Gestures').from_samples(
        NormalDistribution, 3, training, labels=[0, 1, 2], algorithm='labeled')
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

which doesn't make sense since I'm inputing an array, but I guess it thinks I'm supposed to input a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood the documentation. `labels` has to be a list of labels of the length of your `training` set (not of the number of states as it seems to be now). Then, if your training set comprises `N` sequences, the list passed as `labels` should be of length N.

You do not precise what your training set is, but an inconsistency in the lengths of the 2 variables could raise this kind of error (though I'm not an expert in Python).